# MySQL: Duplicate entries pulling

Tags: php, mysql

When I am pulling the MySQL code following:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM product_size AS ps 
INNER JOIN product_type AS pt ON ps.product_id = pt.product_id
WHERE product_type = 'Business Card' 
;
```

Is pulling the following image:

[image]

What I am trying to do is make sure that it only pulls ONE instance of the size on our page when we pull it from our site.

So basically, when we do a selection on our site, I want it to pull ON the size.

When I pull it on our site, it comes up with the following:

http://screencast.com/t/eowXtDol6IOZ

Comment: which of the records do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your product_id is unique so use distinct with product_id instead of all the records.

```
SELECT distinct ps.product_id, ps.*
FROM product_size AS ps 
INNER JOIN product_type AS pt ON ps.product_id = pt.product_id
WHERE product_type = 'Business Card' ;
```

Comment: your query would still pull all 4 of the records in the screenshot.

Comment: than you have to use distinct with size field

Comment: Updated the main post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove unnecessary items easy like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT size, produce_type, p_dimension
FROM 
(SELECT distinct *
FROM product_size AS ps 
INNER JOIN product_type AS pt ON ps.product_id = pt.product_id
WHERE product_type = 'Business Card')
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT rs.size, rs.produce_type, rs.p_dimension
FROM 
(SELECT distinct *
FROM product_size AS ps 
INNER JOIN product_type AS pt ON ps.product_id = pt.product_id
WHERE product_type = 'Business Card') rs
```

Comment: ...try harder... should work. play with column names. run in sql editor; what kind of error?